# Component ngOnInit or Constructor executes multiple times when loaded on button click

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a functionality where I load a component on button click and for that I'm using `ngIf` directive like below:

MainComponent.html

```
<app-sub-component *ngIf = "showSubWizard | async" (boolAddSubClick)="addSubQuestion($event)"></app-sub-component>
```

MainComponent.ts

```
showSubComponent: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

//button click method
subComponentLoadBtn(){
  this.showSubComponent.next(true)
}
```

I added `console.log` in my `ngOninit()` of `SubComponent` and when clicked on button, it shows `console.log` 5 times.

I was earlier using a normal boolean variable but then I saw people suggesting to use behavior subject and that's what I have now but still I'm getting the same issue. I moved my `ngOninit` code to `SubComponent` constructor and still it was getting loaded 5 times.

The issue is that in `ngOninit` of my `SubComponent` I have few api calls and they get executed 5 times.

Comment: will you setup a stackblitz.com?

Comment: Do you mean that if you click the button once you see `ngOnInit` called 5 times, or it you hide/show the component `ngOnInit` is called each time you show it?

Comment: @Vlad274 yes, so if I click the button to load the component (by setting the variable in ngIf to true), ngOninit is called 5 times.

Comment: @Bill Cheng will try to do it tomorrow but I have seen lot of people posting this question and explanation given is that ngIf contains an expression and to monitor the valie change, angular executes it multiple time. The solutions provided though isn't working for me.

Comment: Did you try it in ngAfterViewInit()?